# Unit Tests are failing after updating to Angular 13

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

After updating to Angular 13, lots of my unit tests, that were running without problems on Angular 12, are now failing. What I found more frustrating is that the tests are failing only when running together, but not when I isolate them with `fdescribe`.

I've read that in Angular 13, the `teardown` options is set to true per default, so I tried to opt out globally in my `test.ts` file:

```
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
    teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
  }
);
```

But this didn't work.

My Karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false,
      },
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../coverage/cockpit'),
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
      ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../junit-report/cockpit'),
      suite: 'cockpit',
      outputFile: 'cockpit-tests-report.xml',
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ['mocha', 'kjhtml', 'coverage', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

In the browser console I see lots of the following error:

> NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngTemplateOutlet' since it isn't a known
> property of 'ng-container'

I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the ngrx store. It is now required to reset the selectors in the `afterEach` block

```
afterEach(() => {
    store.resetSelectors();
    fixture.destroy();
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post a copy of your test(s), but I think you might need to import the Angular CommonModule inside it, like this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ]
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

what works for me was, to continue using the `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter`

My Karma config:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/frontend'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    sonarQubeUnitReporter: {
      sonarQubeVersion: 'LATEST',
      outputFile: 'reports/ut_report.xml',
      overrideTestDescription: true,
      testPaths: ['src'],
      testFilePattern: '.spec.ts',
      useBrowserName: false,
      prependTestFileName: 'frontend'
    },
    reporters: ['mocha', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'], 
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
   
  });
};
```