# With destroyAfterEach defaulting to true in Angular 13+, is there any need to clean up in an afterEach?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I often see test suites that include something like

```js
afterEach() {
  fixture.destroy()
  // or TestBed.resetTestingModule();
}
```

Meanwhile, in Angular 13 and later, [ModuleTeardownOptions](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ModuleTeardownOptions)`.destroyAfterEach` defaults to true. Does this do the same job? As long as I'm not explicitly setting `destroyAfterEach` to false, is it redundant to include a fixture.destroy or TestBed.resetTestingModule call?

Note, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72814976/6850209) mentions that at the same time there's a need for ngrx `store.resetSelectors`, so that's maybe one reason to keep the afterEach. But the same answer does fixture.destroy and TestBed.resetTestingModule.